# jQuery :contains pseudoselector sometimes tests on innerHTML, sometimes innerText. Did the behavior change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, system-administration

Our development and test environments seem to have diverged in a mysterious way, and I need to track down what is going on. According to Chrome's dev tools, both environments are using jquery-1.11.0.js. The symptom of the divergence is that in Dev, jQuery code using the pseudo-selector `:contains` is matching on innerHTML, but in Test, it is matching on the innerText. The innerHTML (which comes from our vendor and which we cannot edit) looks like this (note the carriage return after the span):

```
"                  <span class="Required">*</span> ↵                        
Required"
```

As expected, the innerText looks like this:

```
"* Required"
```

In order to hide this text, in Test we can just look for the innerText:

```
$('*:contains("* Required"):last').html("");
```

In Dev, however, we have to pay attention to the innerHTML, using this code:

```
$('*:contains("Required")').has("span.Required").filter(":last").html("");
```

So the workaround is to include both lines in our script, but the important question is, how could jQuery be behaving differently in these two environments? I'm wondering:

- Did jQuery change its behavior for selecting with `:contains` at some point?
- Is there something in our environment that could be affecting this?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.0/src/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L1251 If you're using the same version of jquery in both cases, knowing whether jquery has changed this functionality recently wouldn't be all that important would it? also... no it hasn't changed. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L1458 not in a while at least.

Comment: @KevinB: Thanks for the link. If there had been a recent change, it would have affected how I pursued the issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed (through both view source and inspect element) that the two cases have the exact same html?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is exactly the same, but it appears there was some sort of difference between the two environments. Refreshing both Dev and Test from Prod got them both working the same way. Thanks for your help.